# Inheriting Button not recognized as a class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a class that inherit from System.Windows.Forms.Button Window.
The purpose is to create a button with a special text and special size.

```
public class btAttack : Button
{
    public btAttack (String btTxt) :base()
    {
        this.Text = btTxt;
    }
}
```

But when I put my ":" to inherit, my file is no longer recognize as a class.

Before Inheritance:
[image: Before inheritance]

After Inheritance:
[image: After inheritance]

I also tried to create a partial class to change button but it doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any issue.  This is perfectly valid code.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just an indication that it now recognizes it as a control

Comment: The change in icon is expected. Visual Studio sees it as a component, not just any class. Your interpretation of the difference is incorrect. If you're having a problem with the button, it's not related to the icon in Solution Explorer. Also, you don't need to inherit from `Button` to set the text and size; that's overkill.

Comment: What *problem* is this causing?

Comment: Little lego blocks in the corner.  It is now a component, not just a C# source file anymore.  The .NET 1.0 icons were kinda basic.

Comment: You can decorate the class with `[DesignerCategory("Code")]` if you want the *old* Icon back :) (It also won't try to open a non-existing designer when you double-click it)

Comment: Just FYI, VS Designer requires a default constructor (even it is `private`), without it you won't be able to use you button in the Designer.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot add a new btAttack to create a button.

Comment: Add `public btAttack() : this(string.Empty) { }` as the empty (default) constructor. Remove `:base()` from the other constructor.